# How to get result of str.split inplace for renaming columns?

Tags: python, pandas

My df (imported from xlsx) has 26 columns. 21 of these have names that start with (this is Dutch for 'costs'): `kosten_`.

Two example names: `kosten_farmacie` and `kosten_generalistische_basis_ggz`.

To change these names, I can of course write a dictionary. But with so many columns I think it's better to start with getting rid of the: `kosten_`part.

The following code does this correctly, that is: I get a list of column names without: `kosten_`.

```
df.columns.str.split('kosten_').str[1]
```

Now I want this to get inplace in my df. So I tried:

```
df.rename(columns={(df.columns.str.split('kosten_').str[1])})
```

This gives an Error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Index'`

Is it possible to use `df.rename`. like above?
Maybe an other suggestion?

Comment: Please accept any one of the answers. It helps other people to see that the issue is resolved and solution works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the columns attribute directly with replace

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('kosten_','')
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are trying to use `.rename()`, you can just assign it:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('kosten_').str[1]
```

Comment: Not sure myself anymore why I used rename....  Thanks for your very helpfull answer!! greetings Jan

Answer (score 1):

**Input** :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,2)),columns=['kosten_farmacie','kosten_generalistische_basis_ggz']) 
>>> df
   farmacie  generalistische_basis_ggz
0  0.048584                   0.242719
1  0.099760                   0.376688
2  0.293001                   0.724548
3  0.970689                   0.746782
4  0.952711                   0.992198
5  0.243361                   0.614406
6  0.099160                   0.658806
7  0.107666                   0.646534
8  0.040894                   0.346090
9  0.244920                   0.401649
```

Try this:

```
df.columns = [str(col).split('kosten_')[1] for col in df.columns]
```

**Output**:

```
   farmacie  generalistische_basis_ggz
0  0.048584                   0.242719
1  0.099760                   0.376688
2  0.293001                   0.724548
3  0.970689                   0.746782
4  0.952711                   0.992198
5  0.243361                   0.614406
6  0.099160                   0.658806
7  0.107666                   0.646534
8  0.040894                   0.346090
9  0.244920                   0.401649
```